# jquery - IF works, ELSE doesn't work

Tags: jquery

This is my code. It works on first click but not on second.. More precisely, IF works, ELSE doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".one" ).click(function() {     
        if($('.two').css('margin-right','-345px'))
            $('.two').css('margin-right', '0');
        else
            $('.two').css('margin-right', '-345px');       
    });
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You want to compare the css property with that value (-345px), but this is the syntax to set the css property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".one" ).click(function() {     
        if($('.two').css('margin-right') === '-345px')
            $('.two').css('margin-right', '0');
        else
            $('.two').css('margin-right', '-345px');       
    });
});
```

Comment: What is the difference between === and == ?

Comment: == compares values whereas === compares value and type

Comment: @hiru [Take a look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons) for an in depth explanation.

Comment: In this case there's no significant difference. Some programmers use `===` automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is not correct.

It should be:

```
if($('.two').css('margin-right') == '-345px')
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simplify things:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".one" ).click(function() {     
        $('.two').toggleClass('mymargin');
    });
});
```

And CSS

```
.mymargin{
    margin-right:-345px;
}
```

Comment: I didn't want to edit CSS so I decided to do everything in jQuery, but I'll probably use your method in the future. It is really simple